# what is the step by step process to implement an chat application using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, chat

I am looking for API to develop a Chat application for Android using firebase. I found some sample examples but as web application. So please provide the link and if any step wise instruction lists.

Regards,
Satya

Comment: Google..!!!!!!! https://www.google.co.in/search?q=chat+application+using+firebase&oq=chat+application+using+firebase&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64j69i60.1087j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: here is sample https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/androidchat

Answer (score 1):

The [Firebase Android Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) takes you step by step through building a chat app with Firebase on Android.